# can't assign permission for a folder to a group only one owner works

Tags: centos, directory, permissions, chgrp

I'm trying to change permissions on a folder as root on Centos server using:

```
 chgrp -Rv ftpusers /var/www/html
```

seems like everything is right in verbose. I have two users in ftpusers group however, only user1 can write to html folder. So I have to use 
     chown -R user2:ftpusers /var/www/html
to switch permissions

Why chgrp is not working?

I also used:

```
 chmod -R g+rw /var/www/html
```

But no luck

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Try this: `find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' \;`.

Comment: I found the error in /etc/group, there was a misspell in ftpusers. Steven, thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: You probably still want g+s as Steven describes, or newly created files/directories in those directories won't be in the `ftpusers` group.